# Problem in rendering errors occurred at frontend (aspx) and backend (C#) in an ASP.net project

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

-- Frontend ASPX page --

Here are my branch name & address inputs:

```
Add Branch Name: &nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="NewBranchTbx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
New Branch Name Address: &nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="NewBranchAddrTbx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is my button to insert the data to database:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddNewBrchBtn" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="return validate_newbrchfields();" 
        OnClick="AddNewBrchBtn_Click" />
```

Here is the HTML Span (non-asp element) to display my custom error message:

```
<span id="errlbl" runat="server" style="color: red;"></span>
```

Below is an asp:Label to display other exceptions from C#/MSSQL:

```
<asp:Label ID="explbl" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

Here is my frontend JavaScript code to ensure branch name & address fields are non-empty:

```
function validate_newbrchfields() {

    var newbrname_ent = document.getElementById("<%= NewBranchTbx.ClientID %>").value;
    var newbradd_ent = document.getElementById("<%= NewBranchAddrTbx.ClientID %>").value;

    if (newbrname_ent == "" && newbradd_ent == "") {

        /* error is user submits blank fields */

        document.getElementById("errlbl").innerHTML = "Please enter all new branch details";

        return false;
    }
    else {

        document.getElementById("errlbl").innerHTML = "";

        return true;

    }
}
```

-- Backend C# code --

```
protected void AddNewBrchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // the codes to insert branch name & address to database
    
    } catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            /* error is user enters duplicate record */

            errlbl.InnerText = "the branch name and address you entered already existed";
        }
        else
        {
            explbl.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        explbl.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I intend to use HTML `<span> id="errlbl"` to display my custom error messages.

My HTML span is intended to display an error either when user have left the fields empty (front-end JavaScript function `validate_newbrchfields()` does that) or if user enters a duplicate record (in C# backend, the `catch SqlException` block does that).

When I place `runat="server"` inside `<span>` with `id="errlbl"`, my program is **only** able to display error if user enters duplicate record, but fails to fire front-end JavaScript `validate_newbrchfields()` which causes failure in displaying error if user submits empty fields.

When I remove `runat="server"` inside  with `id="errlbl"`, this causes an error to be thrown at the statement:
`'errlbl.InnerText = "the branch name and address you entered already existed";'` as `'InnerText'` is used for HTML elements at aspx page with `runat="server"`.

But when I disable that statement:
`'errlbl.InnerText = "the branch name and address you entered already existed";'` by commenting it, then the JavaScript `validate_newbrchfields()` works where now my program is able to display an error for user submitting blank fields, but of course will **not** be able to display my custom error message for duplicate record entry.

Any strategies anyone recommend for my program to work in this way:

1. If user submits blank fields (empty branch name & address fields), `validate_newbrchfields()` at the front-end code is fired and error 'Please enter all new branch details' is displayed
2. If user submits duplicate record (record already existed in db), the `catch` block of `SqlException` from back-end code will be executed and error 'the branch name and address you entered already existed' is displayed.

Comment: Why not use the WebForms `RequiredFieldValidator` and `ValidationSummary`?